# How to get the first N sentences from text?

Tags: python, regex, string

I need to get the first N sentences from a text where the last char of the sentence can be a period, a colon, or a semicolon. For example, given this text:

```
Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet. consectetur adipisicing elit; sed do eiusmod tempor.
incididunt ut labore: et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad. minim veniam.
```

The first 4 sentences would be,

```
Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet. consectetur adipisicing elit; sed do eiusmod tempor.
incididunt ut labore:
```

Currently, my code is splitting the string using `.`,`:`, and `;` as the delimiter and then join the results.

```
import re
sentences = re.split('\. |: |;', text)
summary = ' '.join(sentences[:4])
```

But it will remove the delimiters from the result. I'm open to regex or basic string manipulation.

Comment: How would you deal with: _For e.g., It's 5 A.M. in the morning here and my C.D. isn't working very well etc. etc; are you O.K. with this?_?

Comment: @Ben yes, there are "special cases" and the result is acceptable. It doesn't have to be totally perfect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet. consectetur adipisicing elit; sed do eiusmod tempor. incididunt ut labore: et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad. minim veniam."
>>> ' '.join(re.split(r'(?<=[.:;])\s', text)[:4])
'Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet. consectetur adipisicing elit; sed do eiusmod tempor. incididunt ut labore:'
```

Comment: The two regexes are not equivalent. The first only splits on punctuation + space, while the second splits on punctuation(which, I believe, is what the OP wanted).

Comment: @bsdnoobz The first splits on a space that's preceded by punctuation, it was really just a fix of your code. The second one simply finds a pattern using a non capturing group `(?:...)`, which consists of 1 or more non punctuation letters followed by a punctuation. This group is repeated `4` times

Comment: Nice but this will throw an exception when text has less than 4 sentences

Comment: @igo Thanks I have now removed the 2nd solution which would throw an exception. The 1st solution that remains there won't throw any exception

Answer (score 3):

So, I know this question was about using regex to find sentences, but, for the same reason that regex is not the right choice for parsing html, (different classes of grammars), regex is an even worse choice for problems that involve Natural Language.

If your goal is to actually delineate sentences you've got to look for other tools. Personally I would recommend the Punkt sentence tokenizer provided by nltk. Below is an example showing why this is a fundamentally better choice than regex for this task.

```
Punkt knows that the periods in Mr. Smith and Johann S. Bach do not mark 
sentence boundaries.  And sometimes sentences can start with non-capitalized 
words.  i is a good variable name.
```

http://nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html for more info.

Comment: +1 for using `nltk` - it's not perfect, but it does a surprisingly good job of detecting the end of sentences.

Answer (score 1):

Could couple `re.finditer` with `itertools.islice`, and string slicing (to avoid joining back and keeping the delimiter):

```
import re
from itertools import islice

delims = re.finditer('[.:;]', s)
try:
    print s[:next(islice(delims, 3, None)).end()]
except StopIteration:
    print s # whole string instead maybe as there's not enough delimiters
```

Comment: @jamylak it's likely to be slower - can't say I've timed it. I just think it's arguably more readable without capture groups and joins and other bits and bobs... (besides - you'd already taken that answer :))

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
sentenceEnd = re.compile('[.!?][\s]{1,2}(?=[A-Z])')
sentenceLists = sentenceEnd.split(text, re.UNICODE)
```

The above aproach can be used, what it will do is look for a period, and make sure that the next character after that is an uppercase letter and there is a space in between the period and the next letter, this will take care of cases such as A.M. .The text is basically where your original text will be and it will make sure it it unicoded.